# combining arrays and objects dynamically

Tags: javascript

I am creating a nested form which I need to send to the backend to add the product to the database.

I create in state an array of billing cycles. Another array I am creating is an array of objects.

```
let cyclesArray = [annual, monthly, weekly];
let plansArray = [ {value:200, currency: "EUR", billingCycle:"annual"}, {value:220, currency: "USD", billingCycle:"monthly"},{value:20, currency: "CHF", billingCycle:"monthly"}, ....]
```

Before sendind the data to the API, I need to format the array to be an object which would look like this:

```
let objectToSend = {
 name: "whatever",
 bCycles: [
   {
     interval: "annual",
     plan: [
       {
         currency: { name: "EUR", amount: 220 },
       },
       {
         currency: { name: "CHF", amount: 200 },
       },
     ],
   },
   {
     interval: "monthly",
     plan: [
       {
         currency: { name: "CHF", amount: 202220 },
       },
       {
         currency: { name: "EUR", amount: 2021110 },
       },
     ],
   },
 ],
}
```

Basically, I am creating an object, which is an array of billing cycles(arrays containing an array of objects) .

Every billing cycle can have up to 4 plans, grouped on the billing cycle they belong to. I am wondering, how to filter the plansArray and group it based on the billingCycle property and then nest it accordingly in the array with the same name as the billingCycle property. Hope this makes sense.

I am doing it in react and have Redux Saga at disposal.

Comment: You're looking for how to create this object? I don't see reactjs in this question.

Comment: you are correct, it was a mistake on my end since I am using react, but it is not a React question.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use something like this:

```js
let plansArray = [{value:200, currency: "EUR", billingCycle:"annual"}, {value:220, currency: "USD", billingCycle:"monthly"}, {value:20, currency: "CHF", billingCycle:"monthly"}];

// use bCycles as lookup object
let bCycles = {};
for (const {billingCycle: interval, currency: name, value: amount} of plansArray) {
  // if there isn't yet an object present for a certain interval create a new one
  if (!bCycles[interval]) bCycles[interval] = {interval, plan: []};
  // push an object with the name and amount to the interval
  bCycles[interval].plan.push({currency: {name, amount}});
}

let objectToSend = {name: "whatever", bCycles: Object.values(bCycles)};

console.log(objectToSend);
```

The solution makes use of [object destructing assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring).

This answer doesn't take the max of 4 plans per billing cycle into account, but you can add that by adding an `bCycles[interval].plan.length` check before pushing into the array.

I'm not sure if you wanted to group plans with the same interval and currency together, but decided to leave that out since I couldn't imply that from the question.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let cyclesArray = ['annual', 'monthly', 'weekly'];
let plansArray = [ 
  {value:200, currency: "EUR", billingCycle:"annual"}, 
  {value:220, currency: "USD", billingCycle:"monthly"},
  {value:20, currency: "CHF", billingCycle:"monthly"}
];
const objToSend = {
  name: 'whatever',
  billingCycles: loopCyclesArray()
};
function loopCyclesArray() {
  return cyclesArray.map(createBillingCycleObj);
}
function createBillingCycleObj(cycle) {
  return { 
    interval: cycle, 
    plan: filterOnBillingCycle(cycle).map(createCurrencyObj)
  }
}
function filterOnBillingCycle(cycle) {
  return plansArray.filter(planObj => {
    return planObj.billingCycle == cycle;
  });
}
function createCurrencyObj(planObj) {
return {
    currency: { name: planObj.currency, amount: planObj.value }
  };
}
console.log(objToSend);
```